# Removing indentations from flextable facilitated Word table

Tags: r, ms-word, flextable

I am trying to automate the creation of a bunch of Microsoft Word documents using knitr, flextable, and a Word template. I am using Microsoft Word for Mac Version 16.11.1 and R version 3.4.3 on a Linux server. In my Word template, I have a "Normal" paragraph style that indents the first line of all paragraphs.

The issue is that this indentation is repeated in tables that have multi line text. This image should illustrate the issue:

Screenshot of Table

[image]

The relevant code for creating the flextable is just:

```
regulartable(tibble(k,l)) %>%
width(width = c(1,5)) %>%
align(align = "left")
```

As can be seen, the first lines of the paragraphs in the "l" column have indentations.

I was able to remove these indentations by changing the "Normal" paragraph style to have no automatic first line indent, but I would like a way to remove the indentations in R without manipulating the "Normal" style.

I've tried defining a custom paragraph style ("CustomStyle") in the Word template and then wrapping the relevant chunk in `<div custom-style = "CustomStyle"> </div>` or `<span custom-style = "CustomStyle"> </span>`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way of setting the paragraph styles inside a flextable when using knitr and Rmarkdown?

Files needed to reproduce this issue can be found at https://github.com/olkh30/indentation_issue_example

Comment: could you post a reproducible example?

Comment: Just added a link to the .Rmd and word reference files needed to reproduce this issue

Comment: I am afraid it is a bug. I will correct that, I just opened an issue here: https://github.com/davidgohel/officer/issues/121

Comment: it has been fixed, thanks